# How easy/difficult it is to create app to send text field to sql for Android?

Tags: java, android

I have basic knowledge of Java but have never developed for Android.
A friend asked me for an app that seems easy enough to develop but I would need some help for Android.
All the app needs to do is send a text field (for example license plate number) to a predetermined SQL Server database.
Is this easy in Android as it sounds?

Thanks in advance. Cheers.
Darko.

Comment: I'm not sure how we can help you here. Yes, it's perfectly doable and not terribly complicated. I'd say jump in and try to do it, and if you run into specific problems in the process, then that's when to ask those questions here.

Answer (score 1):

That should be easy, but does it need to be a full-blown Android application for that? 
Sounds like a simple webpage with an input-field and a submit button would do the job as well.

Comment: Thanks guys. My first thought was also that a full app is not needed at all, but maybe there is a reason behind it. It will be for a parking lot and maybe they want to avoid having a PC with paid windows license just for running few apps. Or maybe to avoid having a PC on-site at all. That is the only case where mobile app would be worth it that I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with using databases from Java the task is very simple. Just write the code that sends a string to a database. The exact same code you would use on a desktop Java application will do.

The rest is a matter of defining your user interface and obtaining the string. There is a good basic tutorial you can use on the Android developers web site: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html.

The number of code lines in the whole application will be in the range of a couple of dozens.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the license plate information stored in a separate server, but if you also wanted to store some information on the device itself there is a simple [Notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) provided by the Android Developers site that explains how to setup and utilize an SQLite database on the device. This by no means would replace the functionality of a server, but is another Android feature that is at your disposal.